# Python tkinter lisbox bold

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to bold all of the entries for my python tkinter listbox.

I have a list and it enters it into a listbox:

`listbox4.insert(END, Words)`
Does anyone know the code to bold these entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can configure the Font used by the listbox object for all of the text

assuming you are using python 3 and tkinter the code would be like follows (replace the import line with `import tkFont` on python 2)

```
from tkinter import font

listbox4.insert(END, Words)
bolded = font.Font(weight='bold') # will use the default font
listbox4.config(font=bolded)
```

see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_fonts.htm) for some more `tkFont` documentation in case you want to change the font-family, size, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
from Tkinter import *    
import tkFont
sf= tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=36, weight='bold')
lb = Listbox(root , bd=1, height=10, font=sf)
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'tkFont'

Comment: Adding explanation of what your code does is helpful.